# CodeBlocks for Mac won't show up in terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal, codeblocks

As you can see, I've tried running a simple statement but it fails to show up in the terminal. I do have xcode along with xcode command line. I don't know what could be the problem, would it be a problem with the directory where I downloaded xcode? or maybe Codeblocks?

[image: As you can see, I've tried running a simple statement but it fails to show up in the terminal. I do have xcode along with xcode command line. I don't know what could be the problem, would it be a problem with the directory where I downloaded xcode? or maybe Codeblocks?]

Comment: Please post your code !

Comment: there's a screenshot linked to my comment I believe. Sorry :/ new user here

Answer (score 1):

There are several spaces on your command. Either you should remove spaces from that path by renaming directories or better you should escape the space characters using `\` or putting the command inside `"`.

For example:

```
g++ /home/user name/code.cpp // won't work
g++ /home/user\ name/code.cpp // escaping space character
g++ "/home/user name/code.cpp" // using quotation marks
```